# How to convert ordered categorical variable with 4 levels to quantatitve variable

Tags: r, pca, categorical-data, quantitative

Have an ordered categorical variable with 4 levels that weve treated as a factor with 3 additional indicating variables and have concluded only one is significant and want to reassign this single significant variable to the original variable to make it a quantitative variable to perform PCA

Comment: Add some code. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose variable `v1` with levels A, B, C, D. You noticed only B is relevant and want to use this information in a PCA (so you need numerical/quantitative variables).

You can build the variable `v2 <- 1 * (v1 == 'B')`.